# Build Web Deployment Package From Command Line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

Is there any way to build deployment package for a Web Application using Visual Studio 2010 CommandLine ?

Comment: Please mark hivie7510 with answer.

Answer (score 26):

I think this has what you are looking for

```
MSBuild "MyProjectName.csproj" /T:Package /P:Configuration=Staging;PackageLocation="D:\Vishal\Package.zip"
```

I got this from this site: 
http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/web-packaging-creating-web-packages.html

Comment: If you get the OutputPath empty error, add a /P:Platform=AnyCPU argument (no spaces in AnyCPU).

Comment: Also, the PackageLocation will be cleaned first, so watch for deletion of important files. I spat my coffee across the room when I saw it cleaning my main code folder!