# How to create a web deploy package for a website project during TFS build process?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

My current TFS build process just build my website project and output all the files, such as assemblies, web.config, etc.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117083/build-web-deployment-package-from-command-line), I learned how to create a web deploy package with **MSBuild** in command line.

But I want to know how to insert this package step into my current TFS build process.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Create your release package by creating a publish profile through Visual Studio. For this example mine is called Release. this will create you a Release.pubxml file in a folder called Publish Profiles, under your project, check this into source control.

[image: Publish Profile]

Then in your build definition, under the process tab.
Expand the 02. Build > 5 Advanced or similar depending on the version of TFS you are using, add the following to the MSBuild argument text box

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Release
```

ensure the PublishProfile has the same name as the one you created earlier (Release)

[image: web deploy build args]

this will create your deployment package as part of the build

Comment: Thanks. I am using VS2013 Release Management. I want to include this package creation step into the *.proj file, so I automate it through MSBuild. Do you know how to use the publish profile in a *.proj file?

Comment: this is taken from my current set up which uses release managment. it should be the same arguments for a proj file. have you read Colin's ALM corner guide?http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-and-release-management--the-proper-way